# How to position path to node center in tree layout

Tags: d3.js, svg, tree

I have created a cluster tree layout and I want to add custom node styles to selected nodes. To be more precise, I'm adding treemap as node.

I managed to add those, but they are not positioned in the center of node.
I have tried all sort of x,y attributes and translations but I quess I don't get svg that much yet.

Part of code where I add the node is here (for JSfiddle see below):

```
nodeEnter.each(function(d) {
    if (d.status == "D") {
      var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .size([20, 20])
        .sticky(true)
        .value(function(d) {
          return 1;
        });

      var cell = d3.select(this)
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(function(d) {
          return treemap.nodes(d.annotations);
        })
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "cell")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

      cell.append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return d.dx;
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return d.dy;
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d.children ? null : hex2rgb(color(d.parent.name));
        });
    }
 })
```

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czgbh1w8/3/).

L.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted the lines to connect to the middle of the appended rect. I just added a third .attr to your JSfiddle

```
cell.append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return d.dx;
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return d.dy;
        })
        .attr("transform","translate(0,-10)")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d.children ? null : hex2rgb(color(d.parent.name));
        });
```